# Rspec 2.8.0, expect(something) causes ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a fresh repo (non-rails) with rspec 2.8.0.

For some strange reason I can´t use the expect syntax.

**This nonsensical spec:**

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "The Truth" do

  it "is true" do
    expect(true).to be_true
  end
end
```

**causes:**

```
Failure/Error: expect(true).to be_true
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

**spec_helper**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
  config.filter_run :focus

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = 'random'

  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it says that expect syntax comes in rspec 2.11, so I guess 2.8 is old http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax