# Pluralsight RSpec the Right Way: Wrong Number of Arguments for expect(client.url).to eq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

I just started Pluralsights' RSpec the Right Way module. In trying to define `@url = url`, I noticed that it doesn't colorize as in the tutorial video, and received the following failure upon trying to get it to pass. I'm a complete rspec newb, so I need help in dissecting what went wrong here.

Thanks

```
adams-mbp:CommentsDashboard aandrewjeski$ rspec spec/lib/wordpress/comments/client_spec.rb
```

F

**COMMAND LINE**

> Failures:
>
> 1) Wordpress::Comments::Client stores a URL
>
> ```
>  Failure/Error: expect(client.url).to eq 'http://mashable.com/comments/feed'
>  ArgumentError:
>    wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
>  # ./spec/lib/wordpress/comments/client_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```
>
> Finished in 0.00035 seconds 1 example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/lib/wordpress/comments/client_spec.rb:17 #
>   `Wordpress::Comments::Client` stores a URL

**TEXT FILE**

```
 module Wordpress
    module Comments
       class Client

        attr_reader :url

        def initialize url
            @url = url

      end
    end
  end
end

describe Wordpress::Comments::Client do

  it "stores a URL" do
    client = Wordpress::Comments::Client.new 'http://mashable.com/comments/feed'
    expect(client.url).to eq 'http://mashable.com/comments/feed'
  end

end
```

Comment: The code (text file) you posted works fine for me. I think the error  to is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: did you require 'rspec'?

Comment: I don't think so Uri Agassi, I'm not even sure where to put it

Comment: Try adding the line `require 'rspec'` at the head of the source file

Comment: It returned the same error (adding that line to spec/.../client_spec.rb, the file text shown above)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the rspec 2.8.0. and the newer version fixed it.
As it says,
[Rspec 2.8.0, expect(something) causes ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077444/rspec-2-8-0-expectsomething-causes-argumenterror-wrong-number-of-arguments)